# Are old Microsoft Visual C++ 2005/2008 Redistributables safe to remove?

Tags: redistributable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which versions of C++ redistributables can I remove?](https://superuser.com/questions/242699/which-versions-of-c-redistributables-can-i-remove)

Over time, I notice that my Windows computer is accruing more and more Redistributables. Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

In general, is it safe to remove old 2005 versions? Is it safe to also remove old 2008 versions?

Specs:

systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

Comment: Many of those are very small files. What are you concerned about? Do you have any tools that use these redistributables?

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely not safe to delete them because applications may still be using them.  Applications are written against a specific version of the C++ runtime.  An application build using the 2005 runtime will use only that runtime and will not work with the 2008 or 2010 runtime.  So removing a runtime will break any application that is using that version of the runtime.

Comment: But is it safe to remove old versions *of* the 2005 runtime, and old versions *of* the 2008 runtime?

Comment: No it is not safe - applications can be bound to a specific revision of the C++ runtime