# Can I install multiple versions of Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable on my windows 8.1 machine?

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm trying to run an application "Sonic Wall Global VPN client" for the first time on this machine but i'm getting an error in event log :

```
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Program Files\SonicWALL\SonicWALL Global VPN Client\SWGVC.exe".Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```

I looked up the error online and I found that I need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 runtime. I currently have "Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 redistributable" (for x64 and x86) installed on my machine.

My question is: Will installing another version (2008) on my machine cause any problem ?

Comment: No. Installing multiple different versions is fine.

Comment: See this answer [Why are there so many different Visual C++ redistributables?](http://superuser.com/a/619114/337631) for more information

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are there so many different Visual C++ redistributables?](http://superuser.com/questions/173403/why-are-there-so-many-different-visual-c-redistributables)

Comment: The WinSxS folder makes it possible to have several different versions installed. Install the **64Bit VC++ 2008 RTM Runtime** to fix your issue