# Do i need all of those MS SQL server and MS C++ Redistributable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server

Steam has off sale games and i have planned on getting 8 games. With that, i'm starting to prepare my computer to receive those games by cleaning up some useless stuff. Though when i was on "Programs and Resources" i noticed that there are a bunch of MS SQL and MS C++ in there and i want to remove them. I guess they came because i installed VS, though i uninstalled VS because i'm not using it anymore. Do i need them? Here's a list of the programs:

---

- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition [ENU]
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier App Framework
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Objects
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Objects (x64)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 T-SQL Language Service
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU
- Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types
- Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (x64)
- Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server
- Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server (64x)
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.21022
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.30729.6161
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.17
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable - 10.0.40219
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64) - 11.0.60610
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64) - 11.0.61030
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86) - 11.0.60610
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86) - 11.0.61030
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64) - 12.0.21005
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86) - 12.0.21005
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/173403/why-are-there-so-many-different-visual-c-redistributables

Answer (score 3):

I doubt those SQL server instances were installed by a video game, but you absolutely need to keep the C++ redistributables.

Comment: I depends whether these C++ redistributables are there to be redistributed (but non functional) or if they have been installed and referenced by an installed application.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'm not sure were they came from. But i suppose it came from VS. But i'm not sure